# Doctrine many-to-many join without association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, nette

Currently I'm working on doctrine module for favorites which can be reusable in any project and for any entity.

However there is problem with JOINs. I followed [this](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/) article about dynamic mappings and it works great.. Well almost.

I've got `User`, `Article` and `FavoriteItem` entities, where `Article` entity can be added to favorites. Probably link to that github project with readme would be better ([link](https://github.com/Carrooi/Nette-Favorites)).

The problem is mainly in [that](https://github.com/Carrooi/Nette-Favorites/blob/d415319e3f625c6f7610c6f9bae052004fd22232/src/Model/Facades/FavoriteItemsFacade.php#L97) method which should return `FavoriteItem` by `User` and `IFavoritableEntity`, which in our example will be `Article`. As you can see, that method uses native query, but is it possible to use DQL? I know that I would have to use join to table without association, but it seems that doctrine can do that just for one-to-many/many-to-one associations.. I'm right? Or is there any other way how to do that in DQL?

Also do you think there is any way at all how to select in one query (DQL) all `IFavoritableEntities` by one `User`? I just can't imagine any.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found other option which is add possibility to extend `FavoriteItem` entity where I'm able to add field with association to eg. `Article::favorites` field.